# Website not working correctly on mobile Firefox, mobile iOS and Safari

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've made a simple personal website. It seems to be working fine in most desktop browsers.

However on mobile it isn't working correctly. On my android phone it works perfectly fine in Chrome. But I have these issues:

- In Firefox on my Android phone the media query doesn't seem to work and it doesn't scale my website.
- When using browserstack to test the website on iPhones, no browser seems to be working correctly. The transitions between my two pages (About/Skills) does not work at all and the scaling does not work either.
- Finally, the line below the current page (About/Skills) seems to be a little bit too high on Safari on desktop (also tested using browserstack).

What can I do?

Comment: You are using static width values (e.g, 500px) which for the mobile will not work and the content will go off screen. Take a look at css `@media` or use percentage widths wherever you can.

Comment: Also use <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in the document head, maybe not exaclty this but something like that.

Comment: @mikepa88 I am using viewport, and it's actually the same one as you suggested

Comment: @osk True! I didn't see it before.

Comment: This is always the problem using fixed position element. You need to change it every breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting all the widths and heights to percents, not px. Also, on my iPhone 5, it loaded.

**EDIT:** while shrinking the browser screen, I noticed that there is no scrolling.

**EDIT:** Here is something you could use to resize for mobile, but im not exactly familiar with it, so please let me know if im wrong.

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    width:50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  body {
    width:40%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    width:20%;
  }
}
```

Comment: np @osk glad to help :)

Comment: @osk I added an edit so i might work on mobile. just giving you a heads up because i know you dont get notified of edits.